# Automatic configure permission of file to 777 after uploaded

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp

I have my own server. When client uploaded a file to my server through FTP, the permission of the file uploaded is 755. It means if client uploaded a file to my server, client cannot modify the file uploaded to server immediately and have to wait for me to permit the file uploaded to 777.

How can I make the file uploaded from client with permission 777 so that client can modify the file after uploaded.

I am using ubuntu 10.04 and vsftpd FTP server.

Comment: What are the permissions of the folder the files are going into?

Comment: Do you want that for **all** files or just for one / some?

Comment: Do your users really need the files to be 777 to make use of them? Perhaps a chown or chgrp would be a saner alternative than turning off the file systems permissions security system for all of those files?

Comment: I will prepare a folder for my client to upload the file. I need the file that uploaded to the folder I prepared able to be deleted, renamed, and modified by client. So, I think the best is 777.

Comment: In short, something like google drive and dropBox. Client have full power to do with the file inside the directory I prepared.

Comment: FYI: 7 == Read, Write and EXECUTE  Are you SURE you want them to be able to do that?

Comment: More to the point, are you sure you want _everyone_ to be able to modify _everyone else's_ files?

Comment: I am new to server, I don't know what kind of permission should I set in order to allow client to rename and remove the file. I understand that EXECUTE permission is dangerous to server but based on my limited knowledge, it is the simple way for me.

Comment: @edisonTHK ***STOP***. Do absolutely nothing until you go [read the Wikipedia article on Unix file permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions) and *fully understand what they mean*. Blindly changing file permissions like they're some kind of magic voodoo ritual is NOT the way to administer a server. You'll wind up breaking things, creating security holes, or both.

Comment: Also, there's 4 digits in a permission, that first digit makes a lot of difference in cases like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"file_open_mode" is the option you're looking for, check it out in [the VSFTPD man pages](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html). Also keep in mind that the "local_umask" option is also affecting the actual permission.

This should do the trick.

```
local_umask=000
file_open_mode=0777
```

Comment: Nice answer, I will give your a check after I have tried it! By the way, Could it done only with the specified directory?